# Asymptotics of Hypergeometrical function ${}_2F_1$ when integrality is not satisfied

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I am looking for an expression of the asymptotic behaviour for $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ of the Hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ when the condition $a-b \not\in {\mathbb Z}$ is *not* satisfied, in particular when $a=b$.
Previous questions and answer, like [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHypergeometricTransformations.html) using the reciprocation formula, have not considered this case.

If I use the [Euler Hypergeometric transformation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHypergeometricTransformations.html), I could related the limit
$|z|\rightarrow\infty$ to the limit $z\rightarrow 1$ as
$${}_2F_1(a,b,c;z) = (1-z)^a {}_2F_1(a, c-b, c; z / (z-1))$$

Then for $|z|\rightarrow\infty$ the right-hand side gives
$$\sim (1-z)^a {}_2F_1(a, c-b, c; 1) = (1-z)^a \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(b-a)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(b)}$$

This expression seems correct, as long as the argument of the $\Gamma-$function does not hit a pole. But what will happen if $a=b$? What is then the asymptotic behaviour of ${}_2F_1(a,b=a,c; |z|\rightarrow\infty)$?

Comment: http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E8